# Passing two variables via GET to PHP using HTML form

Tags: php, html, get

I'm trying to pass two variables (a search query (String) and a column name (also a String)) via a HTML form.  The first string is entered into a text box and the second is selected from a drop-down menu.

Obviously this method doesn't work:

```
<h3>Search for a Customer</h3>
<form action="search.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="sString">
    <select name="sField">
        <option value="Name">Name</option>
        <option value="HostID">Host ID</option>
        <option value="OrderNumber">Order Number</option>
        <option value="Theme">Theme</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Why does that method not work?  You `do` need to include a `name` for your input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your `<input>` field a name in order for this to work. Unnamed inputs won't get passed through the form post.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a 'name' parameter on your sString input boxes. The `name` parameter is what gets sent back to the server, not the field's ID:

```
<input type="text" id="sString" name="sString">
```

and then in PHP

```
$search = $_GET['sString'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use attribute `name` instead of `value`.

```
<h3>Search for a Customer</h3>
<form action="search.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="sString" name="sString"/>
    <select name="sField">
        <option name="Name">Name</option>
        <option name="HostID">Host ID</option>
        <option name="OrderNumber">Order Number</option>
        <option name="Theme">Theme</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="sString" id="sString" value="">
    <select name="sField">
        <option value="Name">Name</option>
        <option value="HostID">Host ID</option>
        <option value="OrderNumber">Order Number</option>
        <option value="Theme">Theme</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access form entered variables by $_GET array in search.php. To see what is going on try `var_dump($_GET);`